# MySQL the correct way to associate articles with multiple categories

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a layer of categories and sub-categories to my articles table I have the following.

3 tables:

articles (table)

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment  
title   text    NO              
description text    NO              
created timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

articles_to_categories (table)

```
article_id  int(11) NO              
category_id int(11) NO
```

categories (table)

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment  
user_id int(11) NO              
parent_id   int(11) NO              
name    text    NO              
status  int(11) NO              
created timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I am then trying to work out the best queries to access articles in specific categories.

```
select m.title
from articles m
inner join articles_to_categories am on m.id = am.article_id
inner join cats a on am.category_id = a.id
where a.id = 6
```

I am not a mysql dev and this is a side project so I would really appreciate some best practise advice on this.

Is this the recommended way to link cats and subcategories just want to check i am on the right path?

Comment: I don't see a problem. You could add indexes on the columns in the articles_to_categories table.

Comment: I don't see any problem about this solution! I guess that `articles_to_categories. article_id` and `articles_to_categories. category_id ` are foreign keys to the respective tables right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

articles_to_categories (table)

```
article_id  int(11) NO              
category_id int(11) NO
```

It is not a bad idea to have those as FKs.

Also your query can be simpler if no data will be extracted from categories table:

```
SELECT a.title
FROM articles AS a
JOIN articles_to_categories AS atc ON a.id = atc.article.id
WHERE atc.category_id = 6;
```

Comment: ok great thanks both I just wanted to check this through before implementing it ;)